# Docker pull fs hanging while trying to download mysql image(see below screenshot)

Tags: mysql, docker

[image: enter code here]

Every time I try to pull mysql docker image some or other fs pull gets stuck. Repeated ten times already. Need help to resolve this.

Comment: Please check it occur in only case of mysql image